# OpenMP nested for loop without collapse directive

Tags: c, openmp

I'm trying to implement matrix multiplication with OpenMP.

As i found that usually collapse directive is used in nested for loop.

So i also used collapse as below. (this code is belong to feedforward in neural network)

```
for (i = 0; i < net->num_layer-1; i++) {
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(thread) private(j) collapse(2)
    for (j = 0; j < net->mini_batch_size; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < net->layer_size[i+1]; k++) {
            #pragma omp simd reduction(+:sum)
            for (l = 0; l < net->layer_size[i]; l++) {
                sum = sum + NEURON(net, i, j, l) * WEIGHT(net, i, l, k); 
            }   

            ZS(net, i+1, j, k) = sum + BIAS(net, i+1, k); 
            NEURON(net, i+1, j, k) = sigmoid(ZS(net, i+1, j, k));
            sum = 0.0;
        }   
    }   
}
```

But What i want to know is is there any way to implement parallelize without collapse? I also tried like below but the performance is under my expectation.

```
omp_set_nested(1);
for (i = 0; i < net->num_layer-1; i++) {
    #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(net->mini_batch_size) private(j)
    for (j = 0; j < net->mini_batch_size; j++) {
        #pragma omp parallel for num_threads(net->layer_size[i+1]) private(j, k)
        for (k = 0; k < net->layer_size[i+1]; k++) {
            #pragma omp simd reduction(+:sum)
            for (l = 0; l < net->layer_size[i]; l++) {
                sum = sum + NEURON(net, i, j, l) * WEIGHT(net, i, l, k);
            }

            ZS(net, i+1, j, k) = sum + BIAS(net, i+1, k);
            NEURON(net, i+1, j, k) = sigmoid(ZS(net, i+1, j, k));
            sum = 0.0;
        }
    }
}
```

In the thread variable is 100 constant. it would be optimized later but i fixed it now. And also, the result of performance is that with collpase, 0.75sec, and without collapse, 25sec.

So, anyway please let me know is there any way to implement nested loop without collpase which results better performance than collapse.

Comment: *with collpase, 0.75sec, and without collapse, 25sec*  On the face of it that is a remarkable difference in performance.  Are those numbers correct ?

Comment: Yes it is true. That i did again after your comment

Comment: "I'm trying to implement matrix multiplication with OpenMP." Why? Matrix multiplication looks easy, but getting optimal performance is extremely not-trivial. Your time would be better spent finding out how to use a BLAS to do this for you. (Intel MKL https://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-mkl is now gratis and will run in parallel internally where appropriate). (FWIW I work for intel, but not on MKL).

Comment: @JimCownie Thank you for your comment. First, i also have implemented with MKL already. What iam trying is to figure out is finding the situation that openmp is faster than MKL